# Google BigQuery aggregation in one column resolves the other?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a table like this (named `my_table`)

```
| A  | B | C |
+----+---+---+
| -1 | a | x |
|  0 | b | x |
|  1 | c | x |
|  2 | d | y |
|  3 | e | z |
```

How do I do the equivalent of the following in Google BigQuery?

```
SELECT MIN(A) as A_min, B, C
FROM my_table
GROUP BY C
WHERE A > 0
```

The expected result is

```
| A_min  | B | C |
+--------+---+---+
|  1     | c | x |
|  2     | d | y |
|  3     | e | z |
```

The query above works fine in SQL (and just about any other SQL-ish engine I know of), but in BigQuery, it returns the error:

```
SELECT list expression references B which is neither grouped nor aggregated
```

I get why that error happens. My question is: how do I find the corresponding row in column `B` for `MIN(A), WHERE A > 0`?

#### Edit

Some of the proposed answers worked great for the trivial sample table that only includes one unique value for `C`. In a more realistic case, there will be many values for `C`, hence the need to aggregate on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT -1 A, 'a' B, 'x' C UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'b', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'c', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'd', 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'e', 'x' 
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(A AS A_min, B) ORDER BY A LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*, C 
FROM `project.dataset.my_table`
WHERE A > 0
GROUP BY C
```

with result

```
Row A_min   B   C    
1   1       c   x
```

A little less verbose option would be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY A LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` t
WHERE A > 0
GROUP BY C
```

with result

```
Row A   B   C    
1   1   c   x
```

Comment: I'd vote twice if I could. Anything to help you up your stack overflow karma, my friend...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A) rn
    FROM my_table
    WHERE A > 0
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This approach has the advantage of flexibility, because if you instead want all smallest `A` records with ties, all you need to do is replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.

Comment: Thanks. Small detail, this only works for the trivial example above, but not when there is more than one unique value for `C`.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I don't understand your comment, as I have answered given the sample data you actually did provide.  If there is another problem, then please either edit your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Include the columns on your group by clause.

```
SELECT MIN(A) as A_min, B, C
FROM my_table
WHERE A > 0
GROUP BY C, B
```

**or**

```
 SELECT t2.*, t1.C 
    FROM my_table t1 
    INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT MIN(A) as A_min, B
        FROM my_table
        WHERE A > 0
        GROUP BY B) t2 on t2.A_min = t1.A and t2.B = t1.B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE A = (select min(A) from my_table where A > 0)
```

you can also try:

```
Select B
from my_table
where A > 0 
order by A ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

depending on the need of this query.